# What is wrong with using extern in C like that?

Tags: c, extern

I've already searched something abou this but I've still don't understand it..

file1.h

```
extern int *game_array[5];
```

Player.c

```
 #include "file1.h"

   void *delete_player(player_struct *player)
   {
     ... //some code

     game_array[5] = 5;  //undefined reference to `game_array`

     ... //some code
   }
```

When I don't use extern it "work's fine" = I can build it withou errors, but the program's not finished .. 
I suppose the using extern is fine but something is wrong .. 
I want to use this game_array ... array of games on server from all my .c source files, there's only one instance of this array in my aplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *define* `game_array` in one of your `.c` files, and compile/link that file into your executable.

The definition will look like this:

```
int *game_array[5];
```

What your `file1.h` is saying is basically *"There exists a variable called `game_array` somewhere in my project, and it has such-and-such type"*. However, the variable doesn't actually exist until you've defined it somewhere (typically, in a `.c` file).

Comment: But where it should be defined? When I have more .c files? Only in one of them?

Comment: @user1097772: To the compiler and linker, it does not matter in which file you define the variable, as long as the file is included in the build. Conventionally, if you have a declaration like this in a file called `file1.h`, then you'd define the variable in a file called `file1.c` (same name, different extension).

Comment: ok, so file1.h => extern, file1.c definition (that without extern) and when I want to use it in file2.c, I'll only include file1.h into file2.c? Am I right?

Comment: @user1097772: Exactly. Additionally, it is considered good practice to also include `file1.h` into `file1.c`.

Answer (score 1):

The `extern` keyword basically means that the compiler should not complain about the symbol, even if it's not defined, because it will be available at link-time.

So if it's not defined at link-time, you'll obviously have errors.

You need to provide an implementation in one of your C file:

Something like:

```
#include "file1.h"

int * game_array[ 5 ];

void * delete_player( player_struct * player)
{
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing `extern int *game_array[5];` means that somewhere, in some file, there's an actual definition for `game-array` -- i.e., a declaration without the `extern.` You're failing to provide that, so the linker complains that the actual variable doesn't exist anywhere.